# AWS Glue won't rename fields:

Tags: aws-glue

Losing my mind over this, however I'm sure it's something blatantly obvious I'm overlooking.

```
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

## Go out and get the data we need ##
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "emails", table_name = "contactinfo", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")


df2 = df.toDF().show()
df2 = RenameField(df2, "`AccountId`","AcctNumber") # This is the line causing the error
df2 = RenameField(df2, "`id`", "CampMemId")
df2.show()
```

And the error AWS Glue is throwing is the following:

```
 TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the line "toDF()" portion? I see the document mention that RenameField works on a DynamicFrame?  Think you should apply RenameField on the DynamicFrame "df" ?

Also, I think the "`" is NOT required here, since the document mentions, that the tilde is required only, if the referred field names contain any dot in them, ([see this link please)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-RenameField.html).  I have not used RenameField, may be you can check at your end.

Comment: It's odd, I saw one place saying it needs to be applied on Spark DFs, another piece of AWS documentation saying the function was Rename_Field, etc.  I ended up using apply for the transformation anyway since I need to cast them back as strings.  Just wish it didn't drop the REST of the dataset while doing so..

Answer (score 0):

before you convert

```
df2 = df.toDF()

renamedFrame = df.rename_field("original name", "new name")
```

or in your case

```
df.printSchema()
```

*try it with out the back ticks (`) in the orginal name

```
renamedFrame = df.rename_field("AccountId","AcctNumber")
df2 = renamedFrame.toDF()
df2.printSchema()
```

Reference: [Step 4 Filter the data they rename some fields.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html)

Answer (score -1):

Did u try without ` in AccountId.
e.g.

```
df2 = RenameField(df2, "AccountId","AcctNumber")
```

` is needed only if you have dot in column name